# Segue doesn't work? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

My Segue doesn't work for some reason. Please take a look:

[image: I have set the ID for]

I have set the ID for the segue, and invoked the correct method. Why doesn't it work? My app crashes when I click on the button with the following exception thrown:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'MapDetails''*

Comment: You set the identifier name as MapDetails.  And what is the IBAction name of the button?  MapDetails?

Comment: I thought the name of the button doesn't matter?

Comment: You set the identifier name as MapDetails. - that's what I had to do, no?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874200/nsinvalidargumentexception-receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier have a look at this.

Comment: @konyv12 Will you accept some random selected answer just to get it over with, when people spend their free time help you out with the solution like you did with your last question?

Comment: @Sneak I don't know what you are talking about, that was the correct answer for my question... Anyway, Product->Clean didn't work?

Comment: @konyv12 Look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100246/receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier-secondviewcontrollersegue it wasnt me downvoting this question btw. However, there are many threads simliar like this one. Let me know if it doesnt solve your problems I can look into it.

Comment: Please share full screen shot of your storyboard, Do you have set Navigation controller in root of this segue Source View controller?

Comment: I am not sure, that this view controller on left is `Receiver`. May be `Sender`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Comment: I think it was that I set Storyboard ID's for different views within the class. It works now thank u everyone

Answer (score 0):

[image: Select the segue and be sure you named it right]

Select the segue and be sure you named it right